# How do I iterate every TActionClientItem in a TActionManager.ActionBars class?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

**Problem**

I like to use the `TActionManager` component as a better way of managing events and building the menu interfaces either using `TMainMenu` or `TActionMainMenuBar`, for this though we would be using the `TActionMainMenuBar` because of the `ActionBars` property in the `TActionManager`.

One annoying issue I have is with the image indexes sometimes getting lost and more often then not it means having to go through each `ActionBar` item and manually entering the image index again, a pain if you are adding/deleting actions and images etc.

To solve this I came up with the idea of iterating through each `TActionClientItem` and assigning the image index which is determined by its assigned `TAction`.

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
procedure TMyComponent.ReassignActionImages;
var
  I, J, K: Integer;
  Manager: TActionManager;
  BarItem: TActionBarItem;
  Client: TActionClientItem;
  Action: TAction;
begin
  for I := 0 to Owner.ComponentCount -1 do
  begin
    if (Owner.Components[I].ClassType = TActionManager) then
    begin
      Manager := TActionManager(Owner.Components[I]);
      for J := 0 to Manager.ActionBars.Count -1 do
      begin
        BarItem := Manager.ActionBars.ActionBars[J];
        if BarItem.ActionBar <> nil then
        begin
          for K := 0 to BarItem.Items.Count -1 do
          begin
            Client := BarItem.Items[K];
            if Client.Action <> nil then
            begin
              Action := TAction(Client.Action);
              if Action <> nil then
              begin
                Client.ImageIndex := Action.ImageIndex;
                //ShowMessage('Has Action: ' + Manager.Name + ' - ' + Action.Name + ' - ' + Client.Caption);
              end;
            end;
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

While this does seem to work, it does not appear to process child items. I think I need some kind of recursive procedure but I am not sure how to implement that. From what I understand from recursion it basically means running the same procedure within a procedure?

**Steps to reproduce lost TActionClientItem image indexes using one scenario:**

- Create a New Project.
- Add `TActionManager` to Form.
- Add `TAction` to the `TActionManager`, leave ImageIndex as -1.
- Add `TActionMainMenuBar` to Form.
- Select the `TActionManager` in the Form Designer then edit the `ActionBars` property.
- Add a new `TActionBarItem`.
- In the Object Inspector assign the `TActionMainMenuBar` as the `ActionBar`.
- Still in the Object Inspector click the Items (`TActionClients`) property.
- Add a new `TActionClientItem`, give it a caption such as &File.
- Click Items (`TActionClients`) property again.
- Add a new `TActionClientItem`.
- In the Object Inspector assign the TAction (eg, Action1) to the `Action` property.
- Drop a `TImageList` on the Form, and add a bitmap.
- Select the `TActionManager` in the Form Designer again and assign the `TImageList` to the `Images` property.
- Double Click the `TActionManager` and for Action1 change the ImageIndex to 0
- Run the application, notice there is no image showing.
- The &File menu item will also be disabled so just edit the .OnExecute event for the `TAction` if you wish.
- Run again, still no image showing.

**Solution for the above scenario:**

- To make the image visible, edit the ActionBars and find the `TActionClientItem` manually setting the Image index to 0.
- Run the application and the image will show.

So the above is one scenario I can reproduce that shows how the imageindex of a `TAction` is not updated to reflect the changes in a `TActionClientItem`.

There are other times that this has happened (usually when adding, deleting or editing `TActions` and images) where a manual update of the `TActionClientItem` is required.

This is why I decided to try and make a simple component which would ensure the images are syncronized at all times, and that no matter if the `TActionClientItem` imageindex is lost or becomes redundant, if it has a `TAction` assigned that has a imageindex I want that imageindex linked back with the `TActionClientItem`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _Image index getting lost_. `TAction` component has an ImageIndex property. Any component that associates with an Action and has an ImageIndex property will directly inherit that index unless set manually.

Comment: @PeterV. - I cannot remember exact circumstances that cause this but off the top of my head I think this is one scenario: (1) Add new TAction to Action Manager, leave image index as -1, (2) add new client item in action bars (eg for main menu bar), (3) assign the action to the new client item (4) go back to the action manager and change the image index for the TAction - This does not update the client item image index in the action bars. I need to double check but this kind of behavior happens for me with client item image index not updating/getting lost.

Comment: I've followed your steps and I can't reproduce it. You should consider adding the Delphi version tag.

Comment: @PeterV. Delphi XE, I cannot test right now but I am positive there are ways to break the link at designtime between the action bar clients image indexes and the TAction image indexes.

Comment: You can't use a recursive solution until you've identified something you can recurse (and a condition that would cause the recursion to stop). It's very difficult to help you solve a problem that you "cannot remember exact circumstances" to cause it. Spend some time trying to figure out how we can reproduce the problem, so we can help you figure out what's actually making it happen. (I've never encountered this before since the time actions were introduced.)

Comment: @KenWhite I just tried to reproduce and again found a way to break the link between the imageindexes, I have edited the question to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am actually a bit pleased because for once I am able to solve a not so obvious simple problem!

The solution is to call `IterateClients` on the `TActionManager.ActionBars` and by using a callback procedure we can then access each `TActionClientItem`.

Useful documentation links:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/ActnMan.TActionBars

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/ActnMan.TActionBars_Inherited_Members

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/ActnMan.TActionClientsCollection.IterateClients

In code this what I managed to do:

```
TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
protected
  procedure Loaded; override;
  procedure ActionCallBack(Client: TActionClient);
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;
```

and

```
procedure TMyComponent.Loaded;

  procedure SyncImages;
  var
    I: Integer;
    Manager: TActionManager;
  begin
    for I := 0 to Owner.ComponentCount -1 do
    begin
      if (Owner.Components[I].ClassType = TActionManager) then
      begin
        Manager := TActionManager(Owner.Components[I]);
        Manager.ActionBars.IterateClients(Manager.ActionBars, ActionCallBack);
      end;
    end;
  end;

begin
  inherited Loaded;
  SyncImages;
end;

{ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- }

procedure TMyComponent.ActionCallBack(Client: TActionClient);
begin
  if (Client is TActionClientItem) then
  begin
    with TActionClientItem(Client) do
    begin
      if Action <> nil then
      begin
        Caption    := TAction(Action).Caption; // if you want to sync caption
        ImageIndex := TAction(Action).ImageIndex;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```